# Getting value from HTML and Passing to AJAX Function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an HTML code here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs inner-tab">
    <li class="in-tab active" value="1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" ">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="in-tab" value="0"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's an AJAX function:

```
var display = function display() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'db.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {action: 'getAds', },  //something to pass the value of li class= "intab"
        success: function (data) {
           //something
        }
    });
}
```

Now my problem is, how can I pass the value of the class "in-tab" to be processed in the getAds function in db.php? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: which `in-tab`'s value to be considered

Comment: the in-tab's value which is active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `attr()` of jQuery. Try this

```
var display = function display() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'db.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {action: $('.in-tab.active').attr('value') },
        success: function (data) {
            //something
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myList" class="nav nav-tabs inner-tab">
    <li class="in-tab active" data-value="1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" ">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="in-tab" data-value="0"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myList li").click(function(){
    var act = $(this).attr("data-value");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'db.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: { action: act },  //something to pass the value of li class= "intab"
      success: function (data) {
       //something
      }
    });
  });
});
```

is this help?